# Continuously extending a set of independent vectors to a basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, continuity

> **Question:** Let $I=(a,b)$ be an interval and let
>   $$v_i:I\to\mathbb{R}^n,\quad i=1,\ldots,k$$
>   be continuous curves such that $v_1(t),\ldots,v_k(t)$ are linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for every $t\in I$. Can we always find continuous curves
>   $$v_{k+1},\ldots,v_n:I\to\mathbb{R}^n$$
>   such that $v_1(t),\ldots,v_n(t)$ forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ for each $t\in I$?

I know that if $v_1(t),\ldots,v_k(t)$ is a set of linearly independent vectors, then we can extend it to a basis $v_1(t),\ldots,v_n(t)$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$. But how do we ensure that $v_{k+1},\ldots,v_n$ will be continuous?

It is intuitively very clear that there must exist such continuous curves, because there are *a lot* of possible choices for extending the set to a basis. Surely, there must be no problem of doing it continuously, but I cannot find a way to prove it rigorously.

It is easy to do this in $\mathbb{R}^3$ when we have two curves $v_1,v_2$. In that case, we can just take the cross product
$$v_3(t)=v_1(t)\times v_2(t)\in\mathbb{R}^3.$$
But in general, I don't know any explicit expression for producing linearly independent vectors $v_{k+1},\ldots,v_n$ in terms of the previous ones. Is there any?

Comment: It is indeed possible to find such curves. This is equivalent to saying that $I^n$ is an [orientable (differential) manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientability#Orientability_of_manifolds).

Comment: @A.P. Can you please elaborate on it. Thanks.

Comment: @Cora After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/). If the answers you get do not satisfy you, please explain why, so that they can be improved.

Answer (score 3):

Let's call the continuous functions $v_1, \dotsc, v_k$ linearly independent (resp. a basis) if the vectors $v_1(t),\dotsc,v_k(t)$ are linearly independent (resp. a basis) in $\Bbb{R}^n$ for every $t \in I$.

We shall proceed by induction. If $n = 1$ then $k = 0$, so you can choose $v_1$ to be the constant function with value $e \in \Bbb{R}^*$. Now that the base case is cleared we assume that $v_1,\dotsc,v_{n-1}$ are linearly independent functions and we are going to complete them to a basis.

For each $t \in I$ consider the space $V_t \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ spanned by $v_1(t),\dotsc,v_{n-1}(t)$. Since the $v_j$ are continuous in $t$ we can also see $V_t$ as the section of a surface $V \subset X := I \times \Bbb{R}^n$ by the hyperplane $\{x_0 = t\}$. It isn't hard to see that $V$ is homeomorphic to $I \times \Bbb{R}^{n-1}$: for example consider the map
$$
(t, a_1v_1(t) + \dotsb + a_{n-1}v_{n-1}(t)) \mapsto (t,a_1e_1(t) + \dotsb + a_{n-1}e_{n-1}(t))
$$
where $e_1,\dotsc,e_{n-1}$ are the constant functions with values in the standard basis of $\Bbb{R}^{n-1}$. In particular, this means that $V$ divides $X$ in two halves. You can choose as $v_n$ any continuous curve which takes exactly one value for every $t \in I$ and which is entirely contained within one of those halves (without touching $V$).

Comment: Your proof doesn't work. In $\mathbb{R}^2$, take the vector $v_t:=(\cos{2\pi t},\sin{2\pi t})$. The image of the map $t\mapsto <v_t>$ is the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$, so the two halves you want to use are empty.

Comment: @Capublanca You didn't understand my argument. For $v_t = (\cos(2\pi t), \sin(2\pi t))$ I would have a collection $\{V_t\}_{t \in I}$ of lines and $V$ would then be a helical surface (think of twisting a long strip of paper a few times), so the two halves are pretty much not empty.

Comment: @Capublanca Also, "the image of the map $t \mapsto \langle v_t \rangle$" doesn't really make sense to me. Do you actually mean the space $\langle v_t \rangle_{t \in I}  \subseteq \Bbb{R}^2$? In that case, note that $V$ is the image of the "map" $t \mapsto (t, \langle v_t \rangle) \subset I \times \Bbb{R}^2$, where $\langle v_t \rangle$ is a linear subspace of $\Bbb{R}^2$ spanned by a *single* vector.

Comment: You wrote "$V$ divides $\mathbb{R}^n$ in two halves". If i understand your argument, it would be  "$V$ divides $I\times\mathbb{R}^n$ in two halves".

Comment: Ok, now i understand your argument and the proof is clear. Thank you!

Comment: I am trying to understand your answer. Can you please define what $V$ is? Thanks.

Comment: I hope you are still interested, @caffeinemachine. I'm not sure what you mean, because I defined $V$ in the second line of the third paragraph. You can think of $t$ as time and $V$ as the "image" obtained by tracing $V_t$ as it changes over time. For example, in the case from this [past comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1308289/continuously-extending-a-set-of-independent-vectors-to-a-basis/1309574?noredirect=1#comment2662074_1309574) $V$ is a [ruled helicoid](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Helicoid.svg).

Comment: @caffeinemachine In other words, $V$ is the manifold $\left\{(t, \lambda_1 v_1(t) + \dotsb + \lambda_n v_n(t)) \in I \times \Bbb{R}^n : \lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_n \in \Bbb{R}^n\right\}$.

Comment: @A.P. Thank you for the clarification. I can intuitively understand your solution now. Though I cannot see how to show that $X\setminus V$ has $2$ components. One way I can see how to finish the proof along your line of reasoning is by thinking of $V$ as a rank $n-1$ subbunble of $I\times \mathbf R^n$. Then the orthogonal complement $V^\perp$ is a rank $1$-subbundle of $I\times \mathbf R^n$. Since any vector bundle over $I$ is trivial, we can choose a global nonzero section of $V^\perp$ and we are done.

Comment: @caffeinemachine That's a great way of putting it! That's basically what I was hinting at by saying that $V \simeq I \times \Bbb{R}^{n-1}$, but you said it in a rather nice, clean way.

Comment: @A.P. Your proof is what is nice.