# Trying to Understand an Answer: Continuously Extending Bases

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, continuity

The following question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1308289/continuously-extending-a-set-of-independent-vectors-to-a-basis?rq=1)

> **Question:** Let $I=(a,b)$ be an interval and let
>   $$v_i:I\to\mathbb{R}^n,\quad i=1,\ldots,k$$
>   be continuous curves such that $v_1(t),\ldots,v_k(t)$ are linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for every $t\in I$. Can we always find continuous curves
>   $$v_{k+1},\ldots,v_n:I\to\mathbb{R}^n$$
>   such that $v_1(t),\ldots,v_n(t)$ forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ for each $t\in I$?

And the following response was posted by @A.P.

> **Solution.** Let's call the continuous functions $v_1, \dotsc, v_k$ linearly independent (resp. a basis) if the vectors $v_1(t),\dotsc,v_k(t)$ are linearly independent (resp. a basis) in $\Bbb{R}^n$ for every $t \in I$.
>   We shall proceed by induction. If $n = 1$ then $k = 0$, so you can choose $v_1$ to be the constant function with value $e \in \Bbb{R}^*$. Now that the base case is cleared we assume that $v_1,\dotsc,v_{n-1}$ are linearly independent functions and we are going to complete them to a basis.
>   For each $t \in I$ consider the space $V_t \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ spanned by $v_1(t),\dotsc,v_{n-1}(t)$. Since the $v_j$ are continuous in $t$ we can also see $V_t$ as the section of a surface $V \subset X := I \times \Bbb{R}^n$ by the hyperplane $\{x_0 = t\}$. It isn't hard to see that $V$ is homeomorphic to $I \times \Bbb{R}^{n-1}$: for example consider the map
>   $$
> (t, a_1v_1(t) + \dotsb + a_{n-1}v_{n-1}(t)) \mapsto (t,a_1e_1(t) + \dotsb + a_{n-1}e_{n-1}(t))
> $$
>   where $e_1,\dotsc,e_{n-1}$ are the constant functions with values in the standard basis of $\Bbb{R}^{n-1}$. In particular, this means that $V$ divides $X$ in two halves. You can choose as $v_n$ any continuous curve which takes exactly one value for every $t \in I$ and which is entirely contained within one of those halves (without touching $V$).

It is not clear to me what is meant by $V$ in the above proof. Can somebody please explain the meaning of it, and perhaps elaborate the proof more. I asked @A.P. about the meaning of $V$ in a comment but I did not get a response.

Answer (score 0):

To produce a basis $v_{k+1}(t),...,v_n(t)$ of the orthogonal complement to $v_1(t),...,v_k(t)$ at any point you need to produce a basis of the null space of the transpose matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} v_1(t)^T \\ \vdots \\ v_k(t)^T \end{pmatrix}.$$ Since Gaussian elimination is a continuous procedure, you can produce a basis of solutions that depend continuously on $v_1(t),...,v_k(t)$ and therefore continuously on $t$.